# How to stop/kill an autossh tunnel?

Tags: ssh

Now that I have a autossh tunnel, what is correct way to stop it?

There seems to be no easy way to do this. Documentation is unclear on this part.

The easy way seems to be to reboot the machine? Is this correct?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, the proper way to kill `autossh` is simply to kill the process `autossh`, nothing else.

The reason is

```
# file $(which autossh)
/usr/bin/autossh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

that `autossh` is simply a shell script, not a *service*. It starts a new program, in its very last line,

```
exec /usr/lib/autossh/autossh "$@"
```

again not a service. As for `exec` (you can double-check it in the [wiki of the Bash hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec)), it is a shell-builtin command which replaces the current shell with the following command (`/usr/lib/autossh/autossh "$@"` in this case) without starting a new process. So, the **only** way to stop `autossh` is to kill the calling script, for instance

```
pkill -3 autossh
```

(thanks to **dviljoen** for pointing out the importance of using the *-3* flag, see below). Incidentally, killing the `ssh` connection will not work, because the calling command (*i.e.*, the one above) will simply start a new connection as soon as it realizes the old one has been dropped.

Comment: Actually you should kill autossh without the -9.  If a connection has already been made through the tunnel, it will have spawned a child sshd process to handle it.  Killing the parent autossh with -9 will leave the sshd process behind.  The tunnel will still operate until the sshd process times out.  If you use the default signal (-3) on the kill it will gracefully shutdown and take the spawned sshd process with it.

Comment: hi as the -3 is the default kill signal, you don't actually need to explicitly pass -3, you can omit it

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz You **really** sure about it? `SIGTERM` is the default, and that one is `15`. `SIGQUIT` is `3`, see https://superuser.com/questions/352147/what-does-kill-3-mean and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command) -- Also, FWIW, I just checked and `-15` doesn't shut it down, so `SIGTERM` cannot be used.

Comment: And using `pkill` with no signal (= the `default`) also doesn't terminate `autossh`.

Comment: @DanielF you're right, I was confused y the "default signal (-3)" from dvijoen comment

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz I need to correct my statement. `SIGTERM` == `15`, the default Signal, does in fact shut down `autossh` properly. My connection was not established, as `autossh` was waiting for the password (I *thought* I had added the public key...). When attempting to shut it down with `-3` while in this unconnected state, `autossh` and `ssh` got terminated, but when the connection was actually establised, `-3` only terminated `autossh` but left `ssh` connected. `SIGTERM` on the other hand closed them both. But `SIGTERM` did not close it properly when the connection was not fully established

Comment: Wait, actually, `ssh` never got spawned properly, it was not visible in `htop` as a child, when `autossh` was waiting for `ssh` to "enter it's password"... I need a break...

Comment: Well I just tried plain old killall autossh and it killed autossh and all ssh spawned processes, also I think killall is more suitable than pkill since you know the exact name of the program you want to terminate.

Answer (score 6):

run auto ssh with:

`AUTOSSH_PIDFILE=/var/run/tunnel.pid autossh`

kill it with:

`kill pid`

BTW

`pkill -9 autossh` is a wrong

`-9` makes sure the process not exiting gracefully, so `ssh` process is still there when the `autossh` process is killed

without `-9` is still bad, if you have multiple tunnels running, `pkill` will kill them all

correct way is to set `AUTOSSH_PIDFILE` env var then `kill` that pid only

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It appears your final paragraph is your actual answer, while the remainder of your question is a comment on [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1008029/213131). Given the Q&A nature of this site, It would helpful to add enough detail to your answer so it can stand on its own. Thanks for contributing and don't forget to check out the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

**Search for the process:**

> ps aux | grep ssh

*The secon column is the PIDnumber*

**Kill process by PID** :)

> kill -9 PIDnumber

*Use **sudo** if you dont have root privileges.*

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but contrary to the comments above, using `pkill -3 autossh` does NOT kill the sshd child processes for me.

I use this function in my `.bashrc` file.
Bascially, it's like adding a `--kill` argument to autossh.

```
  if [ "$1" = "--kill" ]; then
    ps aux | 
    grep -P "(/usr/bin/ssh|/usr/lib/autossh/autossh)\s.*$2" |
    awk '{print $2}' |
    xargs -r kill
  else
    $(which autossh) "$@"
    echo "" # prevents line wrapping when you kill the ssh process
  fi
```

You can run `which ssh` and `which autossh` to check the paths on your system.

As long as the first argument isn't `--kill`, it just passes the args along to autossh.

This script kills the autossh & ssh instances.
This is important if you are using port forwarding because, killing ONLY the autossh instance doesn't kill the tunnel, it just prevents it from reconnecting if/when it finally does disconnect.

You can also specify a search term (host name) to kill only specific tunnels.

`autossh --kill dbserver1` kills just the connections to dbserver1
`autossh --kill dbserver` will kill dbserver1, dbserver2, etc.
`autossh --kill dbserver` will kill **ALL** autossh connections

To clarify, it SHOULD kill only the SSH sessions started by autossh.

If you run `ps aux | grep ssh` while you have both autossh and ssh sessions running, you will see that the ones started by autossh use the full path (/usr/bin/ssh and /usr/lib/autossh/autossh).
This script only matches results to processes started with the speicifc path.
I did this because I (and I assume most people) usually type `ssh` and not the full path, which keeps it from killing my normal ssh sessions.

Hope this help others.

Comment: any particular reason for `$(which autossh)` instead of simply `autossh`?